# Let A be non zero upper triangular matrix all of whose eìgen values are 0 then How I+A is nilpotent ??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Acc to me .. $I+A$ is nilpotent if  $(I+A)^m =0$  here $m$ is index. And all   eigen value of $A$ are zero therefore all eigen values of  $I+A$ are $1$ that are  not distinct. Let
$Q$ be eigen value of $A$ which is zero then $AX =QX$ here $X$ is eigen vector   Therefore $Ax =0$  but i cannot reach. how we can prove it is nilpotent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the question is posed, the statement is wrong. You can have

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

in which case $$(I+A)^n = 
\begin{bmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\neq 0$$